# Comment comprendre cette phrase « si un citoyen pouvait faire ce qu’elles défendent » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage

Je suis tombé sur cette belle phrase de Montesquieu dans *De l’esprit des lois*:

> La liberté est le droit de faire tout ce que les lois permettent ; et si un citoyen pouvait faire ce qu’elles défendent, il n’aurait plus de liberté, parce que les autres auraient tout de même ce pouvoir.

J'ai du mal à comprendre la partie « si un citoyen pouvait faire ce qu’elles **défendent**, il n’aurait plus de liberté », en particulier l'usage du mot *défendre*. Il me semble que ce que défendent les lois doit être ce que permettent les lois (e.g., les lois défendent les droits individuels), mais dans ce contexte, j'ai l'impression qu'il s'agit plutôt des choses qu'interdisent les lois, d'où ma question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le verbe *[défendre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9fendre)* a deux sens principaux.

1. Lutter contre un adversaire, contrer une attaque.
2. Interdire quelque chose.

L'anglais *[to defend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defend)* n'a conservé que le premier, le deuxième étant considéré comme archaïque.

Dans la phrase, *défendre* est mis en opposition avec *permettre* (*ce que les lois permettent* ... *ce qu'elles (les lois) défendent*), il s'agit donc du deuxième sens.

Montesquieu aurait pu écrire :

> et si un citoyen pouvait faire ce qu’elles défendent de faire

mais ç'aurait été au prix d'une répétition que le français n'apprécie pas...

Answer (score 1):

Ici défendre signifie "interdire", et donc protéger la loi.
Quelques exemples :

- Je vous défends de m'interrompre - Don't interrupt me
- Défense de marcher sur la pelouse - Keep off the grass

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit  bien de *l'interdiction* promulguée par les lois. Si tout citoyen avait le droit de faire ce qui est interdit par la loi, aucun citoyen, qui aurait donc le droit de priver
un autre citoyen de sa liberté  n'aurait pas de liberté  parce que ce « droit » étant aussi celui des autres citoyens, certains de ces autre citoyens pourraient le priver de sa liberté.